# How to set an execution time limit in Ruby/Rails/Passenger/Nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I'm not sure where this is handled.

I need the equivalent of PHP's set_time_limit(seconds)

I'm using Ruby Enterprise Edition, Passenger, and Nginx

Comment: Why you need this? Maybe you need DelayedJob or push messages?

Comment: I need this to make sure the script will not last longer than X seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Timeout](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html) class but IMHO it's very bad idea.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it's a bad idea? It is a common practice in other languages

Comment: Because interrupting anything is bad and no DB safe. I prefer migrating long lasting jobs to another background process. If it is any AJAX call then probably push messages are better idea.